# How should I handle this? Code not validating: Noscript to compensate for lack of JS, but also accommodations to mobile users

Tags: javascript, mobile, validation, noscript

Okay, so I have a paragraph tag which has some text, and the text refers to the direction in which the user can look to view the navigation (I know it's unnecessary, but whatever). Now, I'm trying to kill 2 birds with 1 stone by changing this value from essentially "left" to "top" with javascript (navigation is usually on the left, while on the iphone, for example, it's above); but the efficiency comes in when I try to use noscript.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > -1){
    document.getElementByClassName('navdir')[0].innerHTML = 'up';
  }
</script>

-------------

<p>
   look <span class="navdir">left<noscript><span> (or up, for mobile)</span></noscript></span>
   for the navigation section!
</p>
```

The cool thing is, innerHTML erases the children nodes of span.navdir which is the noscript tag (and it's contents)! My sentence becomes friendly to people who lack javascript, as well as people using the iphone, or both!

I was all happy and stuff until I found that it did not validate. I google'd this up and it's regarding the fact that noscript is actually a block tag, and cannot be inside p, or span, etc.

How can I make this validate while still keeping my new-founded efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the noscript tag and change the contents with JavaScript. Then by definition the original contents will be shown only when the user has JavaScript disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > -1){
    document.getElementByClassName('navdir')[0].innerHTML = 'up';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementByClassName('navdir')[0].innerHTML = 'left';
  } 
</script>

-------------

<p>
   look <span class="navdir">left (or up, for mobile)</span>
   for the navigation section!
</p>
```

(By the way, iPhone is not the only mobile device there is...)

Comment: Thank you, that is also a simpler solution than what I tried to do initially, however, I've decided to just go with CSS's @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){ } thing to set some tags to be invisible. About the thing with the iphone, I realize that, it's just for the sake of simplicity/example that I chose to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty hack, and Juhana's solution is much better, but I'll mention it anyway:

```
<script>
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '.noscript{display:none;}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
</script>
<p>
   look <span class="navdir">left<span class="noscript"> (or up, for mobile)</span></span>
   for the navigation section!
</p>
```

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense as well! Man why didn't I think of any of these solutions..

Comment: Also I believe this is progressive enhancement!